# NullPointerException when accessing another class in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox, actionlistener

I am trying to add an ActionListener to a JButton in the standard way: outside of the method I have `private Actions listener;`and inside of the method I have put

```
listener = new Actions(); // Create the action listener object 

    // Add action listeners to the necessary components
    isDatabaseDefault.addActionListener(listener);
    addEntry.addActionListener(listener);
    editEntry.addActionListener(listener);
    deleteEntry.addActionListener(listener);
    addDatabase.addActionListener(listener);
    editDatabase.addActionListener(listener);
    deleteDatabase.addActionListener(listener);
```

AND that is working fine, no errors are found - here is the ActionListener class:

```
package engines;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import graphicalUI.Tabs;

public class Actions implements ActionListener, SoftwareProperties{
    // Create objects to access methods
    private DatabaseManagement database;
    private Tabs tabs;

    public Actions(){
        this.database = new DatabaseManagement();
        this.tabs = new Tabs();
    }

    // Method that is called when a button is clicked
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Check the source of the action
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Make a new database")){
            System.out.println("Null pointer exception");
            String location = database.makeNewDatabase();
            if(location==null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Your new database was not successfully created. Please try again if you like.", applicationName, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
                        tabs.updateDatabaseMCombo();
            tabs.setDatabaseManagementContent(location, true);
        }
    }

}
```

When I press the button though "Null Pointer Exception" prints out, and the `database.makeNewDatabase();` runs, but as soon as it gets to either of the methods inside the tabs class, I receive the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at graphicalUI.Tabs.updateDatabaseMCombo(Tabs.java:148)     at
>   engines.Actions.actionPerformed(Actions.java:31)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

But the weird thing is, when I run these methods from the same class they work perfectly! Here is the `updateDatabaseMCombo()` method:

```
public void updateDatabaseMCombo(){
        System.out.println("is this method running");
        int sIndex = selectDatabase.getSelectedIndex(); // Get the number value of the selected item
        String selectedItem = selectDatabase.getItemAt(sIndex); // Get the string of the selected item
        System.out.println(selectedItem);
        availableDBs4DM = db.getAvailableDatabases4DB(null); // Get a list of available databases to manage
        selectDatabase.removeAllItems(); // Remove all the current items in the combo
        // Loop through the array and manually add each item
        for(String item : availableDBs4DM)
            selectDatabase.addItem(item);
        // Select the item that was previously selected 
        int search = -1; // Initialise variable to hold the search results
        for(int s = 0; s < availableDBs4DM.length; s++){
            // If a match is found, update the search variable and stop searching
            if(availableDBs4DM[s].equals(selectedItem)){
                search = s;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(search != -1){
            // If the database that was previously selected is still in the JCombobox
            selectDatabase.setSelectedIndex(search);
        }else{
            // Select the default database
            db.setTranslationDefaultDB(selectDatabase);
        }
    }
```

So can anyone work out why I am getting this error please?

BTW, `selectDatabase` has already been initialised as a `JComboBox<String>` object.

---

UPDATE

---

Okay, after some debugging, I found out that my NullPointerException was because I was only declaring the variable out side of the method, like so `private JComboBox<String> selectDatabase;` and I was actually initialising it in a different method, like so:

```
package test;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import test2.Runner;


public class DBCombo {
    private JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();

    public JPanel makePanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        String[] options = {"Why", "will", "this", "not", "work"};
        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(options));

        panel.add(combo);

        Runner main = new Runner();

        JButton doRead = new JButton("Read");
        doRead.addActionListener(main);

        panel.add(doRead);

        return panel;
    }

    public void getComboData(){
        System.out.println(combo.getItemCount());
    }
}

package test2;


import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import test.DBCombo;


public class Runner implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        DBCombo dbc = new DBCombo();

        frame.setContentPane(dbc.makePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        new DBCombo().getComboData();
    }
}
```

Any idea's anyone?

I now think that it is because the action listener and the method are in different packages...

Comment: `graphicalUI.Tabs.setDatabaseManagementContent(Tabs.java:273)` Is where your null pointer exception is occurring. None of the code you posted shows this method, so it's impossible to answer. (And your second chunk of code doesn't call it)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Sorry, the error code I provided was from when I commented out the previous method. Please see my post again for the updated error message; now the code I have posted is relevant to the question I have asked! @Andrew, thank you for that web link. Unfortunately, I don't have time to read it all now, but I'm sure it will come in mighty handy so I will be sure to read it at some point in time!

Comment: which is line 148 of Tabs file?and which database are you using?

Comment: @Heisenbug, sorry for the slow reply. Line 148 is `int sIndex = selectDatabase.getSelectedIndex();`. The database bit is to confusing, and unneccessary to explain but basically `selectDatabase` refers to a `JComboBox<String>` declared outside the method!

Comment: @Andy: read the stacktrace: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at graphicalUI.Tabs.updateDatabaseMCombo(Tabs.java:148) . Exception happened there. Anyway if you don't post an SSCCE is impossible to tell you more.

Comment: Firstly, down voter - who ever you are, I really need some help here so I would have appreciated it if you hadn't done that! If you need me to anything, or don't like something I'm doing please just tell me; give me chance and I will try to put it right. Secondly, @Heisenbug, please see my update on my question! I have found part of the solution to my problem, however, it hasn't fully remedied the situation unfortunately. I have tried to be as clear and precise as possible with my current problem! AND FYI, I did read the stacktrace, but I couldn't see anything wrong with my code...

Comment: @Andy: which database are you using?

Comment: @Heisenburg: I don't know what you mean by the database I am using. My program uses property files to store information, to act as a database... The code I am having trouble with will simply scan the database directory and put there file names in the JComboBox! Therefore, I think they are irrelevant to solving my problem - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Andy: yes it's irrelevant. If you were using SQLite trying to access the db from different threads could be a problem. Btw, you still didn't post an SSCCE. Please do it.

Comment: @Heisenburg Sorry about the SSCCE thing - I have now changed the code in my update to make it shorter, and easier to run! Do I need to do anything else? In my code you will see that my main method and action listener are in a different package to my GUI class. I'm now thinking that this is the cause of my problems because when I was writing that short, self-contained code it seemed to work when both classes were in the same package. However, I don't really want to have to put the actionlistener in the same package as the GUI stuff!

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't have time to read it all now" - if even you as the person most interested in a solution doesn't has the time to even read the information what would help you to get help ... how could you possibly hope that anybody unconcerned might take any time to consider helping? downvote due to attitude..

Comment: @kleopatra: and, for that matter, everyone: please accept my apologies for not reading the SSCCE post at first. However, you will hopefully notice that the last piece of code I have posted is SSCCE! I do fully take on board your comments and will remember them for next time, but as for my attitude: I am fully prepared to try and provide any information that anyone needs - its just on this occasion, I did not know how to present my question. AND I know it's no excuse, but I was actually quite unwell yesterday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, unfortunately it's not exactly what I had in mind or wanted to do, but I have at least got it working now!

It turns out, for some reason still unbeknown to me, that any other class apart from the `Tabs` class itself that called `updateDatabaseMCombo()` or `setDatabaseManagementContent(String, boolean)`generated null pointers! So, I've just bit the bullet and put the actionlistener inside of the `Tabs` class...

Oh well, it's not like my end users will know any different.